# Git: Make sure to pull from branch A to B

Tags: git

I know how to manually pull from a branch A to a branch with another name B:

```
git pull <remote> A:B
```

This pulls remote branch A to B. Easy doing!

But I want to make sure that something like

```
git pull <remote> A
```

doesn't merge into my local branch A (which also exists locally, cause in my case it's the master). Thus, I have to reference my branch B directly to remote branch A.

Is this possible?

Appendix:

To all with the same problem. Make sure that your .git/config has a section like this:

```
[branch "B"]
    remote = <yourremote>
    merge = refs/heads/A
```

This means: a 'git pull' after a checking out branch B merges remote branch A into B. You can easily transfer this example to your problem.

Comment: I would recommend setting up an alias or a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git branch --set-upstream B origin/A` to change the upstream branch.

Then you can use `git pull origin A` or just `git pull` to merge the newest code to `B`.

And you need do all those above at the branch `B`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I needed. One question: If I would do a 'git fetch', it would get all new commits of remote branch A and update the local origin/A pointer, right? I.e. this command above does just affect the subsequent merge action?

Comment: `git fetch` would not update any local branch. While `git pull`, which does a `fetch` then `merge`, would just only affect the current branch. So if you now at B branch, don't worry about it will change the A local branch.

Comment: ok, unfortunately I get in a testing environment: "git branch --set-upstream-to myremotemaster myremote/master" fatal: branch myremote/master does not exist

Comment: @JohnRumpel as the error message says, it is because the remote branch does not exist. You can use `git branch -va` to check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question but it sounds like you want to pull your remote branch A into another branch besides A locally?

If so, then when you can pull remote A into whatever branch you're currently in and it will merge those changes in. So pulling Branch A while in your local branch C will merge branch A with your local branch C.

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding the question, though -- could you maybe clarify it a bit?
Thanks!

Comment: That's it. I wan't to make sure that 'git pull <remote> A' always and within each branch pulls changes to B to hold everything in a consistent state.

Comment: Then you should be good to pull straight into your local branch B. It will merge remote A changes into local branch B :-). From there, you can always merge (or rebase) your local branch B into your local branch A (master branch) if you choose.